# Suppress workbook_open vba script on Excel MAC 2015

Tags: vba, excel

How do I suppress workbook_open vba script on Excel MAC 2015 - SHIFT does NOT work. I have this written to open a file, refresh it, and close everything. But if I want to edit the VBA, I can't open the file without the code running and automatically closing itself.

Comment: (Temporarily) disable macros then open the wb, fix the code (and provided yourself with a back door)  the re-enable macros

Comment: I spent 10 minutes looking for an alternative solution. Not much support out there for Excel/Mac (and VBA isn't even officially supported for Mac)  You'll have to go with @chris's suggestion, which I would do by making the first line of the `Workbook_Open` procedure: `Stop`.  In fact, any compile error would also do the trick, like putting `!@#$%` anywhere.

Comment: Related note: The **Order of Events (OOE)** when opening an Excel workbook is:           *`Workbook_Open` → `Workbook_Activate` → `Workbook_WindowActivate`*                  The worksheet events do **not** automatically fire on workbook open .                         .